# Android Studio 0.6.0 can't create new modules

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I updated android studio to version 0.6.0 today, then I updated my build.gradle using

```
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
```

After that my project with all his dependecies works fine, but if I try to add a new Module, I have tried both manually and with the wizard it won't be recognized by the system.

I added the module in the `settings.gradle` and then I run gradle synch but the `.iml` file is not been generated for the new module and the classes are not recognize as proper java classes.

It also happen if I try to import existing modules in the project.

Anyone out there is experiencing the same problems, it looks weird because until the update everything worked fine

Thanks

Comment: try deleting iml files and restart android studio. Iml files will be auto generated

Comment: Android Studio 0.8.10 doesn't give me this problem. I would re-import the project in the new Studio version after deleting all .iml files and the .idea/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio has released v1.0 recently!  I've actually switched over from IntelliJ 14 Community Edition over to Android Studio v1.0 for all of my Android development now (I do it for a living).  It works well now.

The earlier beta versions were buggy, I tried them before many times in the past but this is the first time I've actually felt comfortable switching entirely over from IntelliJ to Android Studio (yes, I realize one is built on the other).  The preview feature showing several screen sizes on your layout is extremely helpful, and getting started on a fresh computer is simpler as Android Studio also takes care of installing and updating the android SDK if needed.

Highly recommended.  Can download from here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Also: Be sure to delete your .iml project files if you have trouble opening your project in the new version of Android Studio.